# Dart / Flutter and REST client

Tags: flutter, dart, memory, reference

I'm not proficient with Dart's memory model. In my app, I create a client to talk to a REST api, and I pass this client to several widgets. This client handles tokens (as attributes) to authenticate with the API.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      MyAwesomeWidget(client: widget.client),
      MyWidget(client: widget.client),
      SettingsPage(client: widget.client)
    ];
  }
```

The `SettingsPage` widget contains a logout button that nullifies the tokens held by the client. At this point, I'm expecting the client to be unusable by all the widget with a reference to it (don't worry, I have code to handle this case in all the widgets). Am I right here? Or is the client somehow copied into the other widgets?

Comment: If the token data member is defined inside the client, and is not copied externally by the consumer widgets, then it will behave as you expect. If you're only invalidating the token client side (maybe to return the same token later), make sure it is properly encapsulated. If you're invalidating the token server-side, then your consumer widgets should handle failing API requests.

As for the Dart memory model: "Primitives (like int, bool, and num) are passed by value. Objects are
passed by reference. This is the same behavior as in Java for passing
arguments." - Emily Fortuna

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If you make your comment into an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the token data member is defined inside the client, and is not copied externally by the consumer widgets, then it will behave as you expect.

- If you're only invalidating the token client side (maybe to return the same token later), make sure it is properly encapsulated.
- If you're invalidating the token server-side, then your consumer widgets should handle failing API requests.

As for the Dart memory model:

"Primitives (like int, bool, and num) are passed by value. Objects are passed by reference. This is the same behavior as in Java for passing arguments." - Emily Fortuna